# Angular JS Auto Incremented Counter for ID field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I implement an auto incremented counter for `ID` in Angular JS?

Comment: you question will be valid and proper if you show some effort what you have tried in code and where are you facing issue being new to angular.js.
There can be many answers to this question and many could be found by looking at existing SO questions of counter increment in angular.js.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers. Please add details to narrow down the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: This is a fairly simple question.Show what you have down till now, and we can help thereon

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Based off what you said...
You will need a loop

for i=0,1,2...n

Create the element.

//some string

var s="idNum"

setAttribute ('id',s+i)

end for